# How to get a list of all instances of a class in the program, and then convert that string into the actual pointer?

Tags: python, oop

I am attempting to structure some data in a way that will be useful elsewhere in my program.  To that end I have created a class "ProdList" which stores the data:

```
class ProdList:
    instances = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.instances.append(self)
        [a bunch of other stuff where **kwargs is parsed and data is stored]

list1=ProdList([stuff])
list2=ProdList([stuff])
list3=ProdList([stuff])

list_of_lists = [name for name, obj in vars().items() if obj in List.instances]
```

This returns list_of_lists = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3'], which is like 99% of what I want.  But I really want to be able to iterate over these variables (for all lists in list_of_lists) but they are currently strings, not variable names.

I know I could probably iterate over this with exec() to get something, but I'm hoping someone has a better idea.  I don't want to introduce unnecessary instability here, as I'm going to be running this often and under low-supervision.

Comment: Isn’t the list you want `ProdList.instances`?  Im not sure why you’re doing the thing with `vars()` at all.